# Interrupt OutputStream - Android

Tags: android

I'm using a [this](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically) class to upload files in HTTP, my problem is that I noticed when I remove the lan cable from my router the upload stucks as the write call blocks, below shows where it exactly stuck, I tried interrupting the thread but that didn't help either.

Now the question is how can I interrupt outputStream?

```
public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
        throws IOException {
    ...
    //removed code from here for clarity.
    //Can be found in the link above

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        //The code stuck here.
        //using if (Thread.interrupted()) doesn't help
        //as the write blocks when the network cable 
        //removed from the router
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    outputStream.flush();
    inputStream.close();

    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();    
}
```

Comment: Why use `outputstream` for uploading file over HTTP? Why not use a network connection manager? It will automatically determine if an error occurred.

Comment: What should I use that helps me with what I need?

Comment: It will unblock and throw an `IOException: connection reset` after a few minutes.

Comment: So there is no way to do this?

Comment: You need to break the loop.

Comment: What do you mean break the loop? where? how does that help?

Comment: You can use `if (isNetworkAvailable == false) break;` statement inside the `while` loop. Create a method to check the connectivity and get the result, whether `isNetworkAvailable` value changed to `false` or `true`.

Comment: That can not be right! The thread is blocked already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found so far is to do HttpURLConnection.disconnect() from another thread and that seems to be working fine.